# Why aren't my foreign keys working?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, foreign-keys

My create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
    _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rating REAL NOT NULL, 
    timestamp LONG NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES ACCOUNTS(_ID), 
    FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(_ID), 
    UNIQUE (account_id, employee_id, timestamp));
```

However now if I do something like

```
public void deleteAccount(long accountId) {
    mDatabase.delete(
            ACCOUNTS, 
            _ID + " = ?", 
            new String[]{accountId + ""}
    );
}
```

Which is basically `DELETE FROM ACCOUNTS WHERE _ID = some_id` but it isn't cascading through the other tables (employees or main_table) and deleting any records there that link up through the foreign keys.

I do have this code as well:

```
@Override
public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
}
```

Am I misunderstanding how these work? Isn't this what foreign keys are for? Why isn't it cascading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention explicitly if you want any cascading

Change the query like below

```
CREATE TABLE main_table (
    _ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    account_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    rating REAL NOT NULL, 
    timestamp LONG NOT NULL, 
    FOREIGN KEY(account_id) REFERENCES ACCOUNTS(_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(employee_id) REFERENCES EMPLOYEES(_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    UNIQUE (account_id, employee_id, timestamp));
```

Comment: I don't add the cascading in the referenced tables? I define it in the child tables?

Comment: You have to define cascading in the table in which you need cascading @user6313011

Comment: If I try deleting an account from accounts, it still throws a foreign key constraint error

Comment: Nevermind I needed to add the cascade code to the employees table because it also had a foreign key linking to accounts.